# How do I set a button as the focus using tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, focus, python-3.4

I want to open a window with the focus set to the first button, so I don't have to tab to it.
If the widget is an Entry widget I can write

```
widget_name.focus()
```

There does not appear to be an equivalent for a button widget.

Comment: What GUI package are you using?

Answer (score 5):

if you are using Tkinter:

```
buttonname.focus_set()
```

Answer (score 0):

To me there seems to be an equivalent.

```
tkinter.Button = class Button(Widget)
 |  Button widget.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Button
 |      Widget
 |      BaseWidget
 |      Misc
 |      Pack
 |      Place
 |      Grid
 |      builtins.object
 ...
 |  focus = focus_set(self)
 |      Direct input focus to this widget.
 |      
 |      If the application currently does not have the focus
 |      this widget will get the focus if the application gets
 |      the focus through the window manager.
```

and in `tkinter.py`

```
class Misc:
    # ...
    focus = focus_set # XXX b/w compat?
```